# Rspec Spec - User Model validation on unique email account - spec failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec, rspec-rails

Error message I am getting for my failing user spec is

> User did not properly validate that :email is case-sensitively unique.

User Spec as follows:

`it { expect(subject).to respond_to :emails }
  it { expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive }`

```
  it 'has the correct format' do
    expect(subject).to allow_value(Faker::Internet.email).for(:email)
    expect(subject).to_not allow_value("'#{Faker::Internet.email}'").for(:email)
    expect(subject).to allow_value("'some-thing.odd@example.com").for(:email)
  end

  it "requires a unique email" do
    expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email)
  end
end`
```

Im not sure what I actually need to return for this to check case -sensitively uniqie, these are the first specs I am working on so also new to rspec but currently working through this book to understand rspec and testing better http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

User Model:

`validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: ValidateEmail::REGEXP } 
validates :alias_email, format: { with: ValidateEmail::REGEXP, allow_blank: true } 
validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false`

Comment: can you post the validation you added to your User model?

Comment: validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: ValidateEmail::REGEXP }
  validates :alias_email, format: { with: ValidateEmail::REGEXP, allow_blank: true }
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false

Comment: Backticks formating not correct but thats on the user model

Comment: Best to put the above in the question it make it easier to read.

Comment: Also which of all the specs actually fails?

Comment: 'it "requires a unique email" do
    expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email)
  end'

Comment: I'd try it for yourself in console, create two users with the same email address, but different cases, see if you get an error, `user.errors.full_messages`.